# SyntaxError: invalid syntax | list comprehension on enumerated on list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, enumeration

I am trying to run list comprehension on enumerated list but is gives syntax error. here is the code sample that I am trying to run.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
print([(x,y) for x,y in enumerate(list1)])
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-18-dab77e038cc6>", line 3
  print([x,y for x,y in enumerate(list1)])
             ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am expecting a list of tuple with index and value of original list.

Comment: `[(x,y) for ....]`!?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as a screenshot. It's impossible for us to copy&paste the code now.

Comment: you show code with `(x,y)` but error shows code with `x,y` without `()` - so you show wrong code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
z = [(x,y) for x,y in enumerate(list1)]
print(z)
```

result:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Also,  removing the `z` and directly using `print()` also works.

Comment: You could also use the list builtin: `list(enumerate(list1))`, that will give the same value. And it is cleaner and readable.

Comment: @XxJames07- yes,  that would work too.